# Changing background color on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been tasked with cleaning up someone else's code and i'm new to web development stuff and this seems to be a little over my head. I wanted to make the table so that the background of the row and text color change and have looked at examples but could not figure out how to integrate them into this code.

```
      var mydiv = $("<div style=\"height:400px;width:750px;overflow-y:auto;\"></div>");

       var mytab = $("<table style=\"width:750px;height:300px;overflow-y:auto;background-color:Grey;color:White\"></table>").append($("<th style=\"background-color:Black;\"></th>").text("Company Name")).append($("<th style=\"background-color:Black;\"></th>").text("State")).append($("<th style=\"background-color:Black;\"></th>").text("Street Address")).append($("<th style=\"background-color:Black;\"></th>").text("City"));
        for (i = 0; i < companies.length; i++) {
            $(mytab).append($("<tr></tr>").append($("<td style=\"cursor:pointer;\"></td>").text(companies[i].CompanyName).attr("cid", companies[i].KeyID).click(function () {
                var fcd = new FindCompanyDetails();
                fcd.GetRequest("?KeyIDs=" + $(this).attr("cid") + "&AT=" + AT, function (a) {
                    //alert(a.Msg.Result.Address1);
                    populateFields(a.Msg.Result);
                    mydiv.dialog("close");
                });
            })).append($("<td></td>").text(companies[i].StateRegion)));   

        }


        mydiv.append(mytab);
        $(document).find("body").append(mydiv);
        mydiv.dialog({ title: "Choose Matching Company" }, { width: 750 }, {height: 400} );
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: for hover  you can do it very simply using just css  ...  google terms like `css hover`. Please try to research your issues before posting questions here

Comment: Wait, so you're asking us to do your job for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Css

> Put following code in Head section

```
<style type="text/css">
    table tr {background-color:Red;}
    table tr:hover {background-color:Blue;}
</style>
```

Comment: @JoseFlores No Problem : [Use This Site](http://www.w3schools.com/) for this kind of help

Answer (score 2):

Try this with your css:

```
table tr {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
table tr:hover {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

---

Check here:

http://jsfiddle.net/dboxs77z/

---

Answer (score 1):

CSS Is Used for that Purpose

> Put following code in Head section

```
<style type="text/css">
    table tr {background-color:Blue;}
    table tr:hover {background-color:Red;}
</style>
```

Replace Blue & Red With your desired colors